# What is the OAuth error code to output when a nonce has already been used?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect, nonce, openid-provider

An OAuth server (including Open ID Connect providers) must check a client request's `nonce`, if one is specified, to make sure the same one hasn't been used in the last 5 minutes.

All of this makes sense but my question is simply, *what* does a server return in `?error=...` if it has found the nonce was already used?

I have done a dozen or so searches on the web, in RFCs, and in some SDK code but I can't find where an error is returned and what the code would be.

Comment: From where/which spec/RFC did you get this requirement?

Comment: I may be confusing a client responsibility with the server, because there's no explicit requirement stated in the Open ID Connect spec or OAuth's RFCs. None of the specifications actually say *what* do to with the nonce other than to "use it to prevent repeated attacks". Given that, it seems reasonable to me that if the server sees the same nonce twice in a short window then it would return an error. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonce is there to prevent replay attacks on the Client of the token produced by the Provider. The Client sends the nonce to the Provider so that the Provider can include it in the token. This means that the Client needs to keep track of the nonces that it produced, not the Provider. In fact the OpenID Connect spec even says in http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken:

> [other than including it in the token] Authorization Servers SHOULD
>   perform no other processing on nonce values used

So no error code is required here as the Provider doesn't "do" anything with the nonce other than including it in the token.

Comment: What confused me with that wording is that it said no other processing *on* rather than *with*. I figured it was like the `state` parameter which is not to be mucked with but in this case the server could do something with it ... otherwise why not just include a nonce in the state?

Comment: Nonce and state serve different client-side purposes

Comment: Understood but since the server treats them the same (e.g. ignore) the client could include whatever it wants in `state` *including* a `nonce`. You could have a second nonce, etc.